# Can I edit multiple classes on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a div with the class `container`. I decided that this container needed more padding to the top so I added `50px` on to the CSS. I now want to add another container (using bootstraps css), do I need to add a new class to edit on to the container or is there multiple classes for container so I could do something like `container-2`?

Comment: Do you mean if multiple elements can have the same value for the `class` property? If so, then yes. That's kind of the point actually. The `id` property, on the other hand, should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle this is to override the styles using custom classes. Use something like:

```html
<div class="container my-container">
  ...
</div>
```

And then use something like:

```css
.my-container {padding-top: 50px;}
```

Also, you can make use of the utility classes like `pt-4`, etc.

```html
<div class="container pt-4">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is what I was expecting how to do but didn't know what utility classes are but now I do, thanks!

Comment: @DanielD You're welcome. Here's the documentation on [Utilities for layout in Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/utilities-for-layout/)